# Email notifications related to (user) profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications

Right now I have a model called Profile which is associated with a User (basically in Profile I save all the information associated with the User, and in User I store stuff like password, last_sign_in,...).  I want to be able to send some (weekly) emails to the users and I was wondering on just adding a new column to the Profile table.

However, I think that it can happen that I want to send daily too, so I was thinking on creating a new table called "Notifications" that is associated with Profile.  However, I fail to see which kind of association I should do.

A profile can have many notifications, but a kind of notification can be in many Profiles.  How would you guys do that?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on situation, If you have predefined notification list and not generating dynamically then it should be has_and_belongs_to_many in both the models, else in profile model it should be like "has_many => notifications" and in notification model it should be like "belongs_to => profile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends exactly what you are trying to accomplish it sounds like you have a notifications type and also instances of notifications against profiles.

If this is the case then you'd typically have a one to many relationship a profile can have many notifications; in your Profile model include has_many => notifications. And each notification has a type reference; in your Notification model include belongs_to => profile and has_many => notification_types. Which means notification_type belongs to many notifications; in your NotificationType model include belongs_to => notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any association between Notification and Profile/User. You can just create a another model called Notification and have class level method called send_notification. Then you can send notification when ever you want.

If you want to track whether notification is sent or not. You can just have a status/flag column profile. Whenever you send notification update that column.

This is just my opinion.